# Visual Studio: -ResetSettings update current instance instead of launching new one

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editor

I need to reset vssettings whenever it gets modified on a currently opened instance of Visual Studio , I tried to use `devenv -ResetSettings "path to settings"` command, but it launches new instance instead of updating the one is opened at the moment. Tried to get focus using `-edit` argument, but that made to ignore `-ResetSettings`. It should be possible to update settings live, right? How could I possibly achieve that?

Comment: Not quite, my question is about how to deliberately reload modified settings on a currently opened instance. (Added key detail for clarification).

Comment: OK but why not reset through the UI? Why is the command line required?

Comment: I am generating new settings via code and saving it to the file. I want insta-preview so to speak.

Comment: I don't think you can do that via the command line as that will always spawn a new process. Some applications can talk to other instances of themselves but they have to be set up to do it. As far as I'm aware, `devenv` isn't.

Comment: Oh well, thanks anyway.

Comment: @OwenPauling, this isn't a duplicate of the question marked. The OP was talking about specifically updating the current instance via the command line, not UI. This was clarified in the comments